# how to apply onkeyup method in jqgrid new item popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I had a jqgrid configured with my requirements like a pager with new, edit & delete buttons. I stucked on the issue on applying onkeyup function in new item popup's field. I need to caluculate some data on the input of one field and to update this info on another field in the same new item popup. I tried with the jquery syntax like

```
$('#colname1').keyup(
function()
{
  // some calculation on $('#colname1').val();
  $('#colname2') .val(someCalculatedVal);
}); // both these  colname1 & colname2 are defined in the colmodel
```

but it is not working, can any one suggest the right way to implement.

Comment: Implement you code in jsfiddle.com and then paste a link here. I really dont understant what you mean by popup's field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .on() :

```
$(document).on("keyup","#colname1",function(){
  var someCalculatedVal =  $('#colname1').val(); //only a test
  $('#colname2').val(someCalculatedVal);
});
```